Getting two extra bytes in mysql packet for Column Definition and EOF Packet
According to this documentation, the MySQL EOF Packet is supposed to be of 5 bytes, but when I analyze the traffic coming out of my MySQL 8.3.x server, the packet I am getting is as follows:
07 00 00 34 fe 00 00 02 00 00 00
|  header  |       body         |

What are the two extra bytes for? Even the mysql documentation provides the following example for an EOF packet:
05 00 00 05 fe 00 00 02 00

I am seeing a similar situation with the Column Definition in the ResultSet, where according to the documentation there are supposed to be 10 bytes after the "0x0c" packet, whereas this the data I have received after the OxOc packet(inclusive):
0c 3f 00 0b 00 00 00 03 03 42 00 00 00

What am I missing here?
